"'Cannot read properties of undefined' error when configuring Vue in a Serverless application"
I am developing the AWS guide to get started with serverless. This is the link: https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/841ce16b-9d86-48ac-a3f6-6a1b29f95d2b/en-US
Everything was going well until I unplugged the application and it didn't load anything from the Front-end. Check the console and the following error appears:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')
at 8482 (main.js:6:5)
at a (bootstrap:19:32)
at startup:4:87
at a.O (chunk loaded:25:12)
at startup:5:43
at app.8bc5fa16.js:1:15282
When I check the main.js I realize that it refers to the Vue object
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://e7i79e7xm0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1"

new Vue({
   router,
   render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')

More specifically on the line "Vue.config.productionTip = false", what am I doing wrong?
I just need the front to load

This is a Vue2 project right? Did you installed node modules on the production? Have you tried to deploy it to Netlify just to be sure that your project is fine and it's an AWS issue? Does it work locally if you build and preview? Nothing in Github issues regarding this error?
